# Reverse Proxy / Kerberos / Authentication

Tags: javascript, reverse-proxy, kerberos

I am running an API behind a Reverse Proxy with Kerberos based authentication against a user group in our active directory. Everything is woking just fine, accessing the API with direct links pasted into the browser.
If I try to access the API programmatically inside a javascript based react application it fails. We are developping a react application but it can be "minimized" to a simple jquery GetJSON request in a minimal app which then just gets a 401 response and a response header Www-Authenticate: Basic Realm "username/password required".
I am not responsible for the reverse proxy and the user opening the client side application is inside the user group that can brwose to the API.
here ist the minimal example that is not working:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mypanel"></div>

<script>
$.getJSON('https://cool_API.reverse-proxy-url.corp', function(data) {
    
    console.log(data)
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

--> Opening the URL https://cool_API.reverse-proxy-url.corp inside my browser works just fine and the API respond with a proper JSON.

1. Can I change something on my application side to make the getJSON request working?
2. What would be a good candidate to look at (Browser Settings, React Application, Reverse PRoxy settings or Kerberos settings)?